# php how to find the future date closest to today that is not present in a set of disabled dates

Tags: php, arrays, date

As the title suggests, having an array like:

```
$date = [
         '2021-06-25',
         '2021-06-27',
         '2021-06-28',
         '2021-06-30'
        ];
```

Today is June 25, 2021, so I would need to get 2021-06-26

I've tried such an approach but can't find a way to get the date I need

```
$dateComapre = '2021-06-25';

$disabledDay= [
               '2021-06-25',
               '2021-06-27',
               '2021-06-28',
               '2021-06-30'
              ];

function date_sort($a, $b) {
    
    return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
    
}

usort($disabledDay, 'date_sort');

foreach ($disabledDay as $key => $dateSingle) {
    
    // I don't know what check I can do to find the date
    
}

echo $nextDate;
```

Could you give me an idea of ​​how to achieve this?

Comment: First of all, you don’t need `usort` with a comparison function that uses `strtotime` here - `YYYY-MM-DD` is a “sortable” date format, whether one date is lower/greater than the other, can be determined using simple _string comparison_, so a normal `sort` of the array will do.

Comment: You could advance your date by one day in a loop, and check if the value is not contained in your disabled dates array (`in_array`) – if it is, then you have to keep going. Technically, your disabled dates would not even have to be sorted for that.

Comment: use ```in_array```, if date is present, check the next date matches your expectation (date + 1), repeat until it doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate the day like this,

```
$dateCompare = '2021-06-25';
$disabledDay= [
    '2021-06-25',
    '2021-06-27',
    '2021-06-28',
    '2021-06-30'
];
$disabledDay_dic = array_flip($disabledDay);    // for better performance
do{
    $dateCompare = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day",strtotime($dateCompare)));
}while(isset($disabledDay_dic[$dateCompare]));
echo $dateCompare;;
```

Comment: Your method is more elegant, but if the date 2021-06-25 is not present in the array as disabled, it still takes the one after it, how could you modify it to satisfy this case too?

Comment: @Robert: In your question you asked for a future date. Therefore it should be irrelevant if today is in the array or not. It should be never tested for it, as only future days are of concern. Or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm there, I don't know if it's the best way, but it works...

```
$myDay = '2021-06-25';

$disabledDays = [
                 '2021-06-25',
                 '2021-06-27',
                 '2021-06-28',
                 '2021-06-30',
                 '2021-07-01',
                 '2021-10-13'
                ];

for($i = 0; $i < count($disabledDays); $i++):
    
    $dayCheck = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($myDay . ' +'.$i.' day'));
    
    if( ! in_array($dayCheck, $disabledDays)):
        
        echo $dayCheck;
        break;
        
    endif;
    
endfor;
```

Comment: Yes you are there. And what works for you works for you. First step: Make it work. Second step: Make it fast. Third step: Make it nice. Fourth step: Throw it away and start over.